# Custom button field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am using a custom ButtonField in my application. I have used the code from the "[Blackberry Custom Button Field](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-custom-button-field/)" blog post on Coderholic to create a custom button in my app.
Now I want to set the editable property to false for this custom button.

How do I do the equivalent of `button.setEditable(false)` for this custom button?

`mybuttonid.setEditable(false)` is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Override `Field.setEditable(boolean editable)` to track your own custom editable boolean:

```
private boolean customEditable = true;

public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
    super.setEditable(editable);
    customEditable = editable;
    // invalidate(); forces paint(Graphics graphics) to be called
}
```

Override `navigationClick(int status, int time)` to use that boolean to detect whether to react on click events:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {  
    if (customEditable) fieldChangeNotify(1);
    return true;
}
```

If you need a custom visual appearance for disabled state, then also override `paint(Graphics graphics)` to use another color. In this case you'll also need to call `invalidate()` from the `setEditable()`.